# Unable to access localhost from x-ms-webview

Tags: visual-studio-2013, localhost, windows-8.1, winjs, intranet

I have this code in my WinJS `default.html`:

```
<x-ms-webview src="http://localhost/"></x-ms-webview>
<x-ms-webview src="http://display/"></x-ms-webview>
<x-ms-webview src="http://192.168.1.2/"></x-ms-webview>
```

`display` is defined in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 display
```

and `192.168.1.2` -- the one that is *successful* -- is another computer on the network.

This is in my `appx.manifest`:

[image: capabilities]

`display` and `localhost` successfully load in IE on the desktop *and* metro.

My OS is Windows 8.1 Enterprise. I have also completely disabled the Windows Firewall and this has had no effect.

**What else can I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft blocks connections to the local machine except while running from the Visual Studio debugger.<sup>[[1]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0005b94f-8409-4804-88c5-e2f5fcce460a/ipc-between-metro-apps-and-win32-apps#d7f28ce8-4038-406f-b317-849dbfcb126a)</sup>

There is, however, a workaround tool. Quoting from [this post on an MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx):

> Immersive applications (and IE11 on the Desktop) run inside isolated processes known as “AppContainers.” By default, AppContainers are forbidden from sending network traffic to the local computer (loopback).
>   
> [...]
>   I have built a GUI tool that allows you to very easily reconfigure an AppContainer to enable loopback traffic. This tool requires Windows 8 and runs on the .NET Framework v4. When launched, the utility scans your computer’s AppContainers and displays them in a list view. Each entry has a checkbox to the left of it, indicating whether the AppContainer may send loopback traffic. You can toggle these checkboxes individually, or use the buttons at the top to set all of the checkboxes at once. Click Save Changes to commit the configuration changes you’ve made, or click Refresh to reload the current configuration settings.

The aforementioned standalone tool is available from [here](https://www.fiddler2.com/dl/EnableLoopbackUtility.exe).